# 1970s-1980s sci fi novel - Starts on a generation ship and proceeds to planet

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship

The story starts on a generational ship about a boy looking for his father. He comes across a hint to a safety deposit box(?) and finds a laser gun/slide blaster(?) and proceeds to forest planet.

I don't remember the rest but I do recall that the cover had a tree with a boy/young man on it. The tree was green.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the ship, how is it "generational" if he's able to change course? What was the boy's name? How old was the boy? Did he do anything with the gun? Was the boy caucasian/white?

Comment: the boy was early teens maybe didn't have control of the ship in anyway.  he took the gun tried it but never used it; and was taken/transported(?) to a forest planet.  i believe he was white. i do remember he was part of a altercation with his cousin (?) who taunted him about his missing father.this was before he got the gun.

Comment: This sounds like a mix of Slan (1946) and the World of Null-A (1948) by A.E. Van Vogt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt). In Slan, the protagonist is a young boy named Jommy Cross who must retrieve his dead father's secret weapon form an underground vault.  In World of Null-A, after the protagonist is killed, he reawakens on Venus, which has been terraformed into a jungle planet.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly one of the Pip and Flinx series by Alan Dean Foster? Flinx is searching for his father, and there are spaceships and trees (and mind dragons)...

Comment: There are no generation ships in the Pip and Flinx books.